# How to show that $h(-D)\geq \displaystyle\sum_{a\in A_1\\, 1\leq a\leq{\frac{\sqrt D}{2}}} 1$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Here $A_1=\{u;p|u\Longrightarrow \chi(p)=1\}$ with $\chi$ a real quadratic character and $h(-D)$ the class number of the imaginary quadratic field of the fundamental discriminant. This problem occurs in a paper of Pintz and the references given are not easily available. Could anyone please provide some hint as to how to proceed?

Comment: Presumably one proceeds by writing down a set of reduced forms, one for each element in the sum.